# Does VS2017 allow to change tab order of controls in a visual dialog editor for C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, dialog, resource-editor

Say, if I have some dialog box opened in Visual Studio 2017 in the visual editor:

[image]

If I want to rearrange the `tab order` of these controls, the method I was using was to open the `.rc` file in a text editor and rearrange control definitions there:

[image]

So now I'm wondering if there's a way to do this via visual editor?

PS. I found that the "Layout" toolbar has the "Tab order" button:

[image]

but it's always grayed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want "Tab Order" on the "Format" menu (possibly has a `Ctrl-D` shortcut).  Then just click the controls in the tab order you want.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I've been using VS since about VC++ 6.0 and I never knew this option existed in the visual editor :) I'm assuming that after hitting Ctrl+D I can then click blue tab order labels with numbers in the order I want, right. Is there any other way to rearrange them though? Say, if I want to swap two controls.

Comment: @c00000fd You can only specify the order you want.  The closest you can get to swapping is to renumber up to the controls you want to swap, then hit ESC; the rest will keep their order.  (Or just edit the .rc file like you've been doing.)  I've used both approaches over the years.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot add a comment to previous post, I'm posting this as answer.

Yes, `Ctrl+D` in the dialog resource editor will turn on tab order (z-order) editing and you can click on each blue number label to change the order from the beginning.

To start renumbering from a specific control, hold `Ctrl` or `Shift` (used to be `Ctrl+Shift` in older VS) then click on that control's blue label, release the keys and click on the next control that should follow in Tab order.

Say for example you want to make sure a spin control follows its edit box in tab order (for Auto Buddy assignment), hold Ctrl and click on that edit box, release Ctrl and click on spin.

The above trick will allow you to easily swap the two controls as well.